# CSS transform image when hover over a container

Tags: css, image, animation, html, containers

Is there a way using CSS to make a container like:

```
#p-container .p-categories-item
```

affect the images within that div? I have a CSS animation on the images, but I would like it to play when I hover over the entire element, not just actual image itself. Thanks.

Comment: `#p-container .p-categories-item:hover img { /* stuff */ }` should work, right?

Comment: @Thomas Shields: Thanks Man! That worked like a charm! I had tried something similar, but I think I had it backwards like '...item img:hover' Thanks again for your help!

Comment: since that fixed the issue, I've posted an answer. Please mark it as correct as a roadmap to others. Thanks, and glad i could help!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `#p-container .p-categories-item:hover img { /* stuff */ }` to select the image inside the `.p-categories-item` element only when it's being hovered over.